# Python regex query to parse very simple dictionary

Tags: python, parsing

I am new to regex module and learning a simple case to extract key and values from a simple dictionary.

**the dictionary can not contain nested dicts and any lists, but may have simple tuples**

## MWE

```py
import re

# note: the dictionary are simple and does NOT contains list, nested dicts, just these two example suffices for the regex matching.
d = "{'a':10,'b':True,'c':(5,'a')}" # ['a', 10, 'b', True, 'c', (5,'a') ]
d = "{'c':(5,'a'), 'd': 'TX'}" # ['c', (5,'a'),  'd', 'TX']

regexp = r"(.*):(.*)" # I am not sure how to repeat this pattern separated by ,

out = re.match(regexp,d).groups()
out
```

Comment: Don't use regex for this. Use `ast.literal_eval`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use regex for this job. When the input string is valid Python syntax, you can use `ast.literal_eval`.

Like this:

```
import ast
# ...
out = ast.literal_eval(d)
```

Now you have a dictionary object in Python. You can for instance get the key/value pairs in a (dict_items) list:

```
print(out.items())
```

### Regex

Regex is not the right tool. There will always be cases where some boundary case will be wrongly parsed. But to get the *repeated* matches, you can better use `findall`. Here is a simple example regex:

```
regexp = r"([^{\s][^:]*):([^:}]*)(?:[,}])"
out = re.findall(regexp, d)
```

This will give a list of pairs.

Comment: To OP: note that your d object is not a dictionary, but a string representation of a dict; if you made it with d = str(d), better work on the original dictionary!

Comment: I have first tried that way `eval(d)`, but sometimes I may forget to give quotes around variables, then the literal eval will either fail or pick up values assigned to that variable. So, I am going the harder way of regex. get list and in the end make dictionary.

Comment: bad example:  `"a:10"`   then a can pick up already defined value, instead of 'a'

Comment: That's the reason i am looking for regex and if the dictionary fails later, I will catch that error with Exceptions.

Comment: *"I may forget quotes"*: but then you could introduce ambiguity. For instance, `1` and `'1'` are not the same value, nor are `True` and `'True'`, ...Etc. You just should not "forget". Syntax rules are there for good reason, not to annoy people.

Comment: I truly appreciate your suggestions and reasoing and have already voted up. Then, for learning purpose I would like to learn how to deal with repetitive patterns in regex. I will appreciate if you shed some light on regex too.

Comment: Added a section to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Regex would be hard (perhaps impossible, but I'm not versed enough to say confidently) to use because of the ',' nested in your tuples. Just for the sake of it, I wrote (regex-less) code to parse your string for separators, ignoring parts inside parentheses:

```
d = "{'c':(5,'a',1), 'd': 'TX', 1:(1,2,3)}" 

d=d.replace("{","").replace("}","")
indices = []
inside = False
for i,l in enumerate(d):
    if inside:
        if l == ")":
            inside = False
            continue
        continue
    if l == "(":
        inside = True
        continue
    if l in {":",","}:
        indices.append(i)
indices.append(len(d))
parts = []
start = 0
for i in indices:
    parts.append(d[start:i].strip())
    start = i+1

parts
#  ["'c'", "(5,'a',1)", "'d'", "'TX'", '1', '(1,2,3)']
```

Comment: After reading @trincot 's addition to their answer, obviously not impossible :) Nicely done!